# Zel'dovich, Raizer - derive energy equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, energy-conservation

Consider following excerpt from *Zel'dovich, Raizer, Physics of Shock Waves and High Temperature Hydrodynamic Phenomena*:

[image]

I wonder how exactly can I derive (1.10) from (1.9)? For example, (1.9) contains pressure *p* without any derivations applied, while (1.10) includes *p* within a divergence term. The textbook refers to

> using the equations of motion and continuity

however I don't see any straightforward approach to use it.
What makes the situation more confusing to me, most authors (Landau and Lifshitz included) derive energy equation directly from mechanics, starting with mechanical considerations instead of referring to thermodynamic energy equation.

Please advise how to best derive (1.10) from (1.9)?

Comment: The gradiant of pressure comes from the Euler equation.

Comment: Sure, but another part of Euler equation contains substantial derivative of fluid velocity, which is absent in (1.9). And even if I somehow arrive to pressure gradient using Euler equation - where does 'plain pressure' from 1.9 (second term in left part) go?